# MySQL Server and Workbebch installer

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to install MySQL server and Workbench, but I can install only what is on the image. I already tried to delete all files and install again... and NOTHING!! I have WINDOWS 7 32 bits.

What is going wrong?

[image]

Comment: see: [Supported Platforms: MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html) as [Supported Platforms: MySQL Database](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html)

Comment: If you choose to run an unsupported legacy operating system, it's perhaps should not be surprising that other software packages are not available on that operating system.